# Does the "referrer" link still work when the site is already in Beta?

Tags: support, area-51

When I share my link to a site in Area 51 using the [referrer's link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language-usage?referrer=XzTG1Nz01tc01sJEhak_6g2), is this supposed to be used just in the definition/commitment phase, or should/can I use it even when the site is in Beta?

Apparently no-one asked it before, but I don't think the answer is that obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still works, as indicated by following your link:

[image]

However, since the site is already in beta, and commitments are no longer possible, I'm sure it no longer works toward the [Lobbyist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/206/lobbyist) badge.

For that reason, I prefer to create a link to a post on the site itself, in hopes of earning a Booster or Announcer badge there.

Also, for the sake of comparison, you can see that the referral text changes from when the site is in beta:

[image]

Comment: Hello Flimzy, I'm aware it works in that sense, but I was wondering if it was still meant to be used also during the Beta as it is before it. :)

Comment: I just realized that if I share the link for the [Italian SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14570/italian-language-usage?referrer=76bYfwzS7BBLFrrH4GtYig2) which is not in Beta, the message is different. Can you add it to your answer? So it will be more complete. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: My preference is to link to a post on the beta site, for the purpose of earning a Booster or Announcer badge there :)

Comment: Ahah +1 you're right. :)

Comment: Answer updated.